# Visual Studio giving error to update OS 1809

Tags: visual-studio, updates

> Visual studio giving an error to update OS 1809, but the update is not available

I am getting error **visual studio required a newer version of windows to display this content Please update to Windows 10 version 1809(10.0.17763.0) or later**.
But update for **1809** it's not available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.7)

Please suggest me what should I do.

Thanks in Advance

[image: See attach image]

Comment: It's asking you to upgrade Windows, not VS.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: 1809 update for Windows 10 is paused due to data loss bug. Wait till next month, here Microsoft may release it again with a fixed version.

Comment: You are trying to build a *UWP* application. If that application targets Window 10 v 1809, you *can't* develop it on older versions.Either target an earlier version or upgrade your machine

Comment: BTW 1809 is the latest version, which until a few days ago was only available in the Insider ring. Does your application use features available only in 1809? Or could you target a lower version without problems?

Comment: First of all thank you all of you for giving response                                                                                                                        
 if i change the target version to any lower version then it gives error.Is there any solution of this problem which??

Comment: again, wait for re-release of the 1809 update via Windows Update

Comment: I have the same issue, Microsoft have really got some shit developers and every Windows 10 update is released with some major flaw. Really sad